# How can I delete a special character from an array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, special-characters

I have this array:

```
    Array ( [0] => 94857784,maston,traficsoon,5583948,1.0,0.03,ergonomic,18\/1\/2018 8:21:10 AM,8\/2\/2018 11:09:02 AM )
```

I just want to know, How can I replace this caracter \ from the dates values?

My result array should be something like this:

```
      Array ( [0] => 94857784,maston,traficsoon,5583948,1.0,0.03,ergonomic,18/1/2018 8:21:10 AM,8/2/2018 11:09:02 AM )
```

It doesn't matter if the result is an string. I can convert that to array after. 
I'd just like to know how to delete that character.

Comment: *"My teachers gonna kill me if they see the date with that format."*, now c'mon! Anyway, `str_replace("\\", "", ar[0])` where `ar` is your array should do the trick.

Comment: The real answer is that you should figure out where that backslash comes from in the first place and fix it there…

Comment: This looks like a json string that you haven't decoded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stripslashes`

```
$arr = array( "94857784,maston,traficsoon,5583948,1.0,0.03,ergonomic,18\/1\/2018 8:21:10 AM,8\/2\/2018 11:09:02 AM" );

echo stripslashes( $arr[0] );
```

This will result to:

> 94857784,maston,traficsoon,5583948,1.0,0.03,ergonomic,18/1/2018
>   8:21:10 AM,8/2/2018 11:09:02 AM

---

If you have multiple elements on your array, you can `array_map` and use `stripslashes` as callback function. Like:

```
$results = array_map('stripslashes', $arr );
```

Doc: [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: Thank you very very very much! It did solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help @RolandF